# Installing a specific version of python for github action

Tags: python, python-3.6, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, github-actions

I am using `apache-beam[gcp]==2.19` along with `google-cloud-pubsub==1.2.0`. These 2 are currently compatible with `python 3.6.5`. I am using github actions to run tests and deployment. github actions currently supports `3.6.12`. The lowest version that it has is `3.6.7`. How can i download `python 3.6.5` in github actions to run `pytest`?

Comment: Not familiar with github actions but can you create a python virual environment with the desired  python version and run pytests against that?

Comment: how would i get desired python if its not available on github actions.

Comment: I've posted an answer with high level steps that will do what you want. If you include your workflow file in your question, I'd be happy to provide further detail on the steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will take very long to run, but you could do the following steps:

1. Add a step to your workflow to install [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). You will also need to make sure the shim is available to your PATH.
2. Add a step to your workflow to `pyenv install 3.6.5`
3. Then checkout your repo.
4. Add a step to set the local Python version to 3.6.5: `pyenv local 3.6.5`.
5. Run `pytest`.

I anticipate that steps 1 and 2 will take the longest. You can speed this up by perma-caching pyenv and Python 3.6.5 if you know where the files are stored. I've asked and answered myself on how to perma-cache a tool between workflow runs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65801828/how-do-i-cache-an-installed-tool-between-runs-in-github-actions).

Comment: do you have an example I can use that works with the current github action?

Comment: There's a [pyenv-build](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/pyenv-action) action that automates installing through pyenv. Docs include example workflow (be sure to change the `uses: ...@v5` to v8 or whatever its latest release is). It does take ~2 minutes to build Python, and would make sense to cache it.